# Where do I find a copy of Zend PHP Debugger for PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, zend-debugger

I'm trying to find a copy of the Zend debugger for PHP 5.4.

I've followed the various tutorials on the web telling me to download the Studio Web Debugger from the zend website, but unfortunately it only contains the binaries for PHP 5.3 (and below).  I can't seem to find any mention anywhere of the Zend Debugger for PHP 5.4 ... it seems like they no longer make it and instead want you to use their full Server product instead.

Comment: This does not directly answers your question, but you might be fine in using xdebug instead: http://xdebug.org/ It also supports PHP 5.5 beta so far. Zend is getting lazy in keeping up with PHP development. So much for "The PHP company", sometimes taglines catch irony over time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazingly, Zend, "The PHP Company", will sell you Zend Studio, but they will not package a 5.4 version of the Studio Debugger in the related download.  I would think they could get an updated version out since 5.4 has been released for over a year...

In any event, a work around has been making the rounds on the Internets.

Here is a full set of [instructions](http://irtbfdev.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/zend-debugger-for-nginx-php-54/) for a Debian based system.

It was based largely on this Zend Forum post...
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=47568&f=59#p148893

The gist is to lift a 5.4 debugger file from an old Zend Server download an use it instead.

Many thanks to the original posters.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - however recent versions of the debuggers for php 5.3.x and php 5.4.x are included in the free version of Zend Server, so you can install that, make a copy of the .dll or .so that you need, and then uninstall it.

I did this to get at a version of ZendDebugger.dll that would work with php 5.3 and Zend Studio 10, but there is a 5.4 version of Zend Server aswell.